# ggplot legend issue w/ geom_point and geom_text

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am trying to use `geom_point` to illustrate the count of my data. I would also like to annotate a few of the points in my graph with `geom_text`. When I add the call to `geom_text`, it appears that it is plotting something underneath the points in the legend. I've tried reversing the order of the layers to no avail. I can't wrap my head around why it is doing this. Has anyone seen this before?

```
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10
    , y = 1:10
    , label = sample(LETTERS,10, replace = TRUE)
    , count = sample(1:300, 10, replace = FALSE)
)

p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, size = count)) + geom_point()
p + geom_text(aes(label = label, size = 150, vjust = 2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This happened to me all the time.  The trick is knowing that `aes()` maps data to aesthetics.  If there's no data to map (e.g., if you have a single value that you determine), there's no reason to use `aes()`.  I believe that only things inside of an `aes()` will show up in your legend.

Furthermore, when you specify mappings inside of `ggplot(aes())`, those mappings apply to *every subsequent layer*.  That's good for your x and y, since both `geom_point` and `geom_text` use them.  That's bad for `size = count`, as that only applies to the points.

So these are my two rules to prevent this kind of thing:

1. Only put data-based mappings inside of `aes()`.  If the argument is taking a single pre-determined value, pass it to the layer **outside** of `aes()`.
2. Map data **only for those layers that will use it**.  Corollary: only map data inside of `ggplot(aes())` if you're confident that every subsequent layer will use it.  Otherwise, map it at the layer level.

So I would plot this thusly:

```
p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point(aes(size = count)) 
p + geom_text(aes(label = label), size = 4, vjust = 2)
```

Comment: Your two rules are pertinent!

Comment: Very useful tips to know for the future, I'm still trying to wrap my head around best practices w/ ggplot2. Do you have any suggestions for subsetting the data object to plot? For example, if you only want to annotate the first and last point? I've been using something like `geom_text(data = df[grep("xxx", df$label) , ] , aes(x = ...))`. Is there a better way to go about doing that?

Comment: Chase - that's a good question.  It might be wise to make a new question out of it; I have some vague notions, but chances are somebody else has a concrete idea.

Comment: the `directlabels` package facilitates this sort of custom annotations, IIRC

Answer (score 19):

or, if you need to specify the size of text inside the aes, then legend = FALSE suppress drawing the legends of the geom:

```
p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, size = count)) + geom_point()
p + geom_text(aes(label = label, size = 150, vjust = 2), show_guide = FALSE)
```

Comment: Ah, it never occurred to me to use that at the layer level.  Nicely done.

Comment: Just a small info: "legend" has been replaced by "show_guides": "legend" argument in geom_XXX and stat_XXX is deprecated. Use show_guide = TRUE or show_guide = FALSE for display or suppress the guide display."