# Why does the ggplot legend show the "colour" parameter?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have the following example:

```
data <- structure(list(a = c(-1.25549186262767, -0.840855480786298, -
0.635371312524283, 
-0.602907981454667, -0.472166385166945, -0.285773634866154, 0.0701427664273268, 
0.138108224803923, 1.38435934347858, 1.71144087270237), b = c(-3.44400412039417, 
0.675644682353751, -1.04793816522475, -7.38303347186651, 2.34519166466874, 
0.334780748573386, 4.76806919070976, 4.8633533150074, 3.50106026731172, 
-1.27172351054143), c = c(-3.02376206439776, -2.56390769080574, 
-1.48659913867609, -1.27976202274701, -0.368725655874139, 1.08537150160227, 
3.98619381956471, 4.50687017428731, 4.10341582203292, -1.61769414438858
), d = c(5.71851494232005, 2.90539833491649, 2.75195159216204, 
2.73478241733301, 2.65941820902101, 2.60630235726839, 3.34836154776286, 
3.62938300664006, 4.61153521538016, 5.56230567213863), e = c(8.98703236551896, 
4.5660296657415, 4.32487774825464, 4.29789523068949, 4.17945528847841, 
4.09598014088541, 5.26217626511884, 5.70382046327322, 7.24733897758039, 
8.74153894964533)), .Names = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")

ggplot(data, aes(x=a, y=b)) + geom_point() + 
    geom_line(aes(x=a, y=c)) + 
    geom_line(aes(x=a, y=(c - d), colour="red")) +
    geom_line(aes(x=a, y=(c + d), colour="red")) +
    geom_line(aes(x=a, y=(c - e), colour="blue")) +
    geom_line(aes(x=a, y=(c + e), colour="blue"))
```

I want the labels to be "d" and "e", but they are instead being given the value of the "colour" field.  Two questions:

1) How can I eliminate the legend entirely?
2) If I want to include the legend, how can I have it set to specific values rather than the colour?

Comment: very related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15418590/7941188

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The important thing to remember here is that items inside of `aes()` will map data to aesthetics. If you are setting a constant value(s), then you can move that information outside of `aes()`. A slight modification of your code yields:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=a, y=b)) + geom_point() + 
geom_line(aes(x=a, y=c)) + 
geom_line(aes(x=a, y=(c - d)), colour="red") +
geom_line(aes(x=a, y=(c + d)), colour="red") +
geom_line(aes(x=a, y=(c - e)), colour="blue") +
geom_line(aes(x=a, y=(c + e)), colour="blue")
```

Which gives you what you are after without any legend. I like @koshke's approach for including a legend above so won't duplicate that. The other approach you could take would be to perform your data manipulation outside of the call to `ggplot2()` and then `melt()` it into long format before plotting. That would shorten your call to `ggplot()` since you could get rid of the multiple calls to `geom_line()`, but there's obviously the overhead of preprocessing the data. Probably 6 in one, 1/2 dozen in the other for this problem, but something to keep in mind for future problems.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221168/) post for more information on `aes()` and suppressing legends.

Answer (score 6):

is this what you want to do?

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=a, y=b)) + geom_point() + 
    geom_line(aes(x=a, y=c)) + 
    geom_line(aes(x=a, y=(c - d), colour="d")) +
    geom_line(aes(x=a, y=(c + d), colour="d")) +
    geom_line(aes(x=a, y=(c - e), colour="e")) +
    geom_line(aes(x=a, y=(c + e), colour="e")) +
    scale_colour_manual(name="legend title", 
                        values=c("red", "blue"),
                        breaks=c("d", "e"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Eliminating the the label could be done via adding `+ opts(legend.position = "none")` option also.

Comment: 'opts' is deprecated. Use 'theme' instead. (Deprecated; last used in version 0.9.1)