# adding legend to overlaying density plot in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, density-plot

I have an overlaying density plot from two datasets, created with ggplot2.

```
  g <- ggplot(data = result_A,
              aes(x = log(cap_universal))) +
    geom_density(fill = "lightblue") +
    geom_density(data = result_B,
                 fill = "purple",
                 alpha = 0.25) +
    xlab("Complete Automation Probability") +
    ylab("Density")
```

I got what I wanted, a plot looks like this:
[image]

However, I have tried many ways but still cannot add legends to this plot. There is no error message, but the legend just won't show.

Will appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you tried the `theme` function and its various arguments? You might want to refer to this document: http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-legend-easy-steps-to-change-the-position-and-the-appearance-of-a-graph-legend-in-r-software

Comment: @user6606453, have you seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15418302/ggplot2-how-to-show-the-legend) I think it has something to do with your dataset. Can you dput your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine your data sets `result_A` and `result_B` into a single dataset, where the thing these differences are is specified as some factor, e.g. "thing":

```
result_A$thing <- "A"
result_B$thing <- "B"
result_AB <- rbind(result_A, result_B)
```

Then instead of calling two datasets with separate calls to `geom_density`, specify  it once with `fill = thing` and specify your colours and alphas manually, e.g.:

```
ggplot(data = result_AB, aes(x = log(cap_universal))) + 
  geom_density(aes(fill = thing,
                   alpha = thing)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("light blue", "purple")) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(1, 0.25)) +
  # assuming here that the "result_A" data will plot first as "A" should
  # order before "B" in factors, though can't test w/out yr data
  xlab("Complete Automation Probability") +
  ylab("Density")
```

This should produce a legend showing what colour your factors "A" and "B" are, which I assume is what you're after.

This is more in-line with the philosophy of `ggplot2`. However it might also work if you wrap both your `fill` calls inside `aes`, e.g. `geom_density(aes(fill = "lightblue"))`. (It's impossible to test this though, because you haven't got a reproducible example above)

Comment: Thank you for the idea of combining the two dataset into one. But I was trying to create an overlaying density plot to demonstrate the difference between these two datasets.

Comment: I've amended the answer so hopefully it "overlays" onto the other data set better for you. Is this what you're after? Note the assumption that your result_A will order first. You might have to switch the factor levels if it comes out the wrong way.

Comment: Thank you very much @Mob. This is very helpful indeed!