# Place a border around points

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to place a black border around points on a scatterplot that are filled based on data, using ggplot2. Also, I would like to avoid having a legend entry for the black border since it will be on each point. Basically I'm looking for this plot, but with a black border around each point.

```
df <- data.frame(id=runif(12), x=1:12, y=runif(12))
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y))+geom_point(aes(colour=id), size=12)
```

[image: the plot I want, except it doesn't have borders around the points]

As a bonus, I'd like to not have a legend entry for the black border. My best try is:

```
df <- data.frame(id=runif(12), x=1:12, y=runif(12))
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y))+geom_point(aes(fill=id, colour="black"), size=12)
```

Which gives:

[image: not at all the plot I want]

I don't understand why that doesn't give me what I want, and worse (for my education in ggplot2) I don't understand why it doesn't seem to map fill color to anything! Any help?

Perhaps if I can get the outline and fill mapping right I can use a hack like the one in hte last set of figures [here](http://wiki.stdout.org/rcookbook/Graphs/Legends%20%28ggplot2%29/) to turn off the legend.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

It's a bit obscure, but you have to use `pch`>20 (I think 21:25 are the relevant shapes): `fill` controls the interior colo(u)ring and `colour` controls the line around the edge.

```
(g0 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y))+geom_point(aes(fill=id), 
       colour="black",pch=21, size=5))
```

**update**: with recent ggplot2 versions (e.g. 2.0.0, don't know how far back it goes) the default guide is a colourbar.  Need `g0 + guides(fill="legend")` to get a legend with points as in the plot shown here.  The default breaks have changed, too: to *exactly* replicate this plot you need `g0 + scale_fill_continuous(guide="legend",breaks=seq(0.2,0.8,by=0.1))` ...

[image]

Related but not identical: [how to create a plot with customized points in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958025/how-to-create-a-plot-with-customized-points-in-r) . The accepted answer to that question uses the layering technique shown in @joran's answer, but (IMO) the answer by @jbaums, which uses the `pch=21` technique, is superior. (I think `shape=21` is an alternative, and perhaps even preferred, to `pch=21`.)

PS you should put `colour` **outside** the mapping (`aes` bit) if you want to set it absolutely and not according to the value of some variable ...

Comment: Thanks Ben. Is there any way to change the stroke (outline) width using this method?

Comment: I don't see one (I tried setting `width` and `lwd`), sorry.

Comment: Thank you for this - never would have gotten there without this answer!

Answer (score 35):

The first question's a gimme:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
    geom_point(aes(colour=id), size=12) + 
    geom_point(shape = 1,size = 12,colour = "black")
```

And, oh, you *don't* want an extra legend. I think that does it then:

[image]

Comment: Interestingly a guide doesn't show up for the second geom_point - I don't really understand why that is, but since it is what I wanted anyway I'll worry about it another day

Comment: Oh, I see why - because it is not inside an aes() call

Comment: @DrewSteen - looks like you got it, I asked a similar question a while back since it took me a while to figure that out too. I'm not sure if/what would be made out of date by the introduction of ggplot 0.9: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221168/ggplot-legend-issue-w-geom-point-and-geom-text

Comment: This is nice, but fails if you're using jitter.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik You are right. Is there a solution? I'd like to do do something similar using geom_jitter.

Comment: @Seanosapien sure, just "jitter" the points manually (transform the values in `df`) using either `rnorm` or `jitter`. You may want to store these values in a new variable in case you need raw values downstream.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue, but I needed a solution that allows for jitter, too. For this you do need to use a pch that is a filled shape with a border and a grid.edit function from gridExtra package. Using your example:

```
df <- data.frame(id=runif(12), x=1:12, y=runif(12))
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=id))+geom_point(pch=21, colour="Black", size=12)

library(gridExtra)
grid.edit("geom_point.points", grep = TRUE, gp = gpar(lwd = 3))
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same question, but perhaps since I was using geom_map with latitudes and longitudes, the other answers as of January 2020 didn't work for me.

Restating the question, where the following does not have a black outline around the points:

```
df <- data.frame(id=runif(12), x=1:12, y=runif(12))
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y))+geom_point(aes(colour=id), size=12)
```

If I declared both the color and fill in the aesthetic and then used shape 21, problem solved.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour=id, fill=id), 
  shape = 21,size = 12,colour = "black")
```

[image: Points Outlined in Black]

Comment: Hi @windyvation what if my data is plotted so the size depends on a variable, how can I add a black outline to the circles? My plot would be like this `ggplot(data, aes(x = Region, y = func, label=NA)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = scaled_val, colour = value), shape = 21, colour = "black") +
  geom_text(hjust = 1, size = 2) +
  theme_bw()+
  scale_color_gradient(low = "lightblue", high = "darkblue")`

Comment: @Ecg modifying the code above, the following  works for variable size:   library(tidyverse)
size_x <- 1:12
df <- data.frame(id=runif(12), x=1:12, y=runif(12), size = size_x)
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour=id, fill=id), 
             shape = 21,size = size_x,colour = "black")

Answer (score 1):

If you want more control (for example, borders on points with various shapes and transparencies), use the `fill` aesthetic with shapes `21:25`

```
ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Width, fill = Species, shape = Species), data = iris) + # notice: fill
    geom_point(size = 4, alpha = 0.5) + # transparent point
    geom_point(size = 4, fill = NA, colour = "black") + # black border
    scale_shape_manual(values = c(21:23)) + # enable fill aesthetic
    theme_classic()
```