# How to set geom_point fill for ggplot in rpy2 from Python?

Tags: python, ggplot2, rpy2

I'm making the following simple plot with ggplot using rpy2:

```
from rpy2.robjects.lib import ggplot2
from rpy2.robjects import r, Formula
# R iris dataset
iris = r('iris')
p = ggplot2.ggplot(iris) + \
    ggplot2.geom_point(ggplot2.aes_string(x="Sepal.Length", y="Sepal.Width", colour="Sepal.Width"), fill="white") + \
    ggplot2.facet_wrap(Formula('~ Species'), ncol=2, nrow = 2) 
p.plot()
```

It all works except the `fill="white"` part. I'd like the fill to be white for all the points while the colour (i.e. the point border colour) to be set by `Sepal.Width`. How can this be done? thanks.

Comment: I think the only way around this is to use `shape=1` and abandon `fill=`, which will have the same effect I believe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an obscure trick: it requires to set `pch`

See this answer:
[Place a border around points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10437442/place-a-border-around-points)