# How can I modify the sizes of the dots of legends? and how can I export the plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, export, size

[image]

plot pane

change the sizes and export the plot

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of your problem. Without knowing how you created your plot, it's difficult to help.

Comment: Assuming ggplot2, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/29307725/3358272 for the use of `override.aes`. For exporting, have you tried `ggsave`?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, J Barrera! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (please be explicit about non-base packages), sample representative data (perhaps via `dput(head(x))` or building data programmatically (e.g., `data.frame(...)`), possibly stochastically), perhaps actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: As @r2evans mentioned, ```ggsave``` is the way to go to export your plot. The basic documentation is here: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggsave.html