# R plots: use dark borders around colored points

Tags: r

I have some data that I have to plot as coloured points, and I would like to get a dark border around the points. 
Here is the code:

```
plot(x, y, pch=c(rep(16, 6), rep(17, 6)), cex=1.3, col=my_colors)
```

This produces coloured points without border... How can I add a dark border?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10437442/place-a-border-around-points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fill-able plotting characters instread of the solid ones.

```
x<-1:6
y<-1:6
my_colors <- rainbow(6)

plot(x, y, pch=c(rep(22, 3), rep(23, 3)), cex=1.3, bg=my_colors)
```

[image]